# Ruby bindings - the scope of local variables versus constants

Tags: ruby, binding, scope, constants

I want to run eval of strings to define both local variables and constants.
I want to do this in different namespaces.  I can do this with local variables
but not with constants.  Is there a way to modify the NameSpaces module below
so that constants defined in one binding/namespace are not seen by another?

```
# Example run under ruby 1.9.1
module NameSpaces
  def self.namespace(namespace)
    return binding
  end
end

b1 = NameSpaces.namespace("b1")
b2 = NameSpaces.namespace("b2")

# Set a 'x', then check to make sure its still set in the scope of 'b1'
puts b1.eval("x = 1") # => 1
puts b1.eval("x")     # => 1

# Check to make sure 'x' is NOT set in the scope of 'b2'
begin
  puts b2.eval("x") # NameError exception expected here
rescue Exception => e
  puts e.to_s       # => undefined local variable or method `x'
                    #  for NameSpaces:Module (THIS IS AS EXPECTED.)
end

# Set constant 'C' and do the same checks
puts b1.eval("C = 1") # => 1
puts b1.eval("C")     # => 1

# Check to make sure 'C' is NOT set in the scope of 'b2'
begin
  puts b2.eval("C")  # (I DON'T GET AN EXCEPTION.  NOT AS I HAD HOPED FOR.)
rescue Exception => e
  puts e.to_s
end
```

Thanks so much for the look.  I'm very stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you are observing is normal. When you execute `C = 1` in the scope of a call to `NameSpaces.namespace`, a constant "C" is defined on `NameSpaces`. (You can confirm this by trying `NameSpaces::C`.)

To get the effect you want, you need to use the binding of an *anonymous module*. Try this:

```
namespace1 = Module.new.class_eval("binding")
namespace2 = Module.new.class_eval("binding")
namespace1.eval("C = 1")
namespace1.eval("C")
=> 1
namespace2.eval("C")
NameError: uninitialized constant #<Module:0xf09180>::C
```

Note that any constants which are defined in Object (i.e. the global scope) will be available within the code passed to `eval`, and if the values of such constants are changed in the evaluated code, the change will be visible globally!

(Even if you evaluate code in the context of a BasicObject, which doesn't inherit from Object, the evaluated code can *still* access constants defined on Object, by prefixing the name with '::')

Comment: Thanks Alex.  That's informative.  I might be missing something but I think this type of evaluation fails my first test cases for local variables.  I think that using this method I'd have to parse the expressions passed to my program to determine a particular form of eval.  The program I'm hoping for will take all end-user supplied input and parse it as an expression but in the user's own namespace rather than the program's.

Comment: @dinman2022, actually, I tested it with local variables, and it works.

Comment: I don't want locals to fall out of scope between calls. Example:\`class MyClass
  def initialize
    @spaces        = {}
    self.namespace = 'default'
  end

  def namespace=(id)
    @namespace = @spaces.has_key?(id) ? @spaces[id] : Module.new
  end

  def do_me(exp)
    if exp =~ /^namespace/
      self.namespace = exp.split[1]
    else
      @namespace.class_eval(exp)
    end
  end
end

input = %q{
x = 1
x # => DIES HERE
namespace new_one
x # should fail
}

c = MyClass.new
input.each_line { |l|
  begin
    puts c.do_me(l)
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e
  end
}`

Comment: @dinman2022, the line which starts with `@namespace =` should be `@namespace = (@spaces.id[id] ||= Module.new.class_eval("binding"))`. Sorry, I'll edit my answer.